# bpy data out of sync with the actual scene

Tags: python

My python command line shows names for objects that are not on the scene anymore when I try to autocomplete on

```
bpy.data.meshes
```

like

```
bpy.data.meshes['Cube']
```

is a valid reference even though there is no object named `Cube` on the scene anymore and no error or warning is issued, my script just goes on and does nothing .

I'm supposed to keep the Python API in sync with the scene manually - and in this case, how ? - or I'm missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bpy.data.meshes` is all of the meshes in the all of the scenes. Meshes are different from objects, a mesh would be like the vertex positions while an object is made of a mesh, and contains the modifiers, materials, etc.

If you have an object selected you can see the name of the mesh by going to: `Properties Panel > Data` here you will see the name of the object's mesh, you can also get a list of all the meshes in the scene.

I am guessing that you have a cube, or an object that at one point was a cube and that is why the mesh name is `Cube`.

If you want to get rid of meshes that aren't currently being used then you can do something like this

```
import bpy
for mesh in bpy.data.meshes:
    if mesh.users == 0:
        bpy.data.meshes.remove(mesh)
```

Comment: yes, but why they don't go away when the associated object is not there anymore ?

Comment: @user2485710 if the mesh isn't being used by any objects, then it will be deleted on the next opening of `Blender` or by Ctrl + Shift + O, and reloading your current file. Just make sure to save first. If that doesn't get rid of it then it is still in use. A way to check if it is not in use is go to `Properties Panel > Data` and find the name of the mesh in the dropdown and see if there is a `0` beside it

Comment: and what's the equivalent via Python ? How to force this update via script

Comment: @user2485710 check my original post, I updated it